# Store Output of Grep In Array

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep

I have netCDF files in two directories that I want to ultimately find a single variable in and compare, and if not equal I want to remove both files. What I have so far:

```
dir1=(/working/test/temp1/*.nc)
dir2=(/working/test/temp2/*.nc)
```

Here I'm trying to store the output of grep into an array. I found these methods on the site, but neither to work.

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#dir1[@]}; ++i)); do
  dir1_arr=($(ncdump -h "$dir1" | grep "Temperature = "))
done

for i in $dir1; do
dir1_arr=($(ncdump -h "$i" | grep "Granules = "))
done
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach, but I want to then compare the granule values that should be stored in two separate arrays, then delete the corresponding files if the granules don't match. First I need to get past this step of storing the output of grep in array.

Comment: When I do `echo ${dir1[@]}`, nothing prints to the screen.

Comment: Your `dir1` array is empty. Is the directory you care about **really** the absolute path `/working/...` or should that just be the relative path `working/...`?

Comment: @EdMorton I want the array to contain the netCDF files in that directory path. It should probably be the relative path.

Comment: @anubhava yes echoing that does show all files

Comment: Does `echo "${dir1[@]}"` work?

Comment: @anubhava Yes that also works...prints all the files.

Comment: ok try this now: **`dir1_arr=(); for d in /working/test/temp1/*.nc; do dir1_arr+=($(ncdump -h "$d" | grep "Temperature = ")); done`**

Comment: @anubhava That's also not working. The issue seems to be with `*.nc`. I do have other files in that directory that are not netCDF and the loop works on the other files. It doesn't ncdump them, but still tries to perform the command and prints to the screen.

Comment: Run all the given command using `bash -x script.sh` and post the output in question otherwise it is difficult to understand from comments,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All presented attempts lack quoting of the `$(…)`, which is essential because the `grep` output contains multiple words. See the end of this answer for a solution. In addition, there are other errors:

---

> ```
> for ((i = 0; i < ${#dir1[@]}; ++i)); do
>   dir1_arr=($(ncdump -h "$dir1" | grep "Temperature = "))
> done
> ```

This didn't work because in the loop body

- you used `$dir1` instead of `${dir1[i]}`
- you used `dir1_arr=` instead of `dir1_arr+=`

---

> ```
> for i in $dir1; do
> dir1_arr=($(ncdump -h "$i" | grep "Granules = "))
> done
> ```

This didn't work because

- in the `for` command head you used `$dir1` instead of `"${dir1[@]}"`
- in the loop body you used `dir1_arr=` instead of `dir1_arr+=`

---

> ```
> dir1_arr=(); for d in /working/test/temp1/*.nc; do dir1_arr+=($(ncdump -h "$d" | grep "Temperature = ")); done
> ```

This didn't work because of the wrongly absolute path `/…`.

---

A correct version is

```
dir1_arr=()
for d in working/test/temp1/*.nc
do  dir1_arr+=("$(ncdump -h $d | grep 'Granules =')")
done
```